# How to import a material-ui slider with react in a web page?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, material-ui, slider

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<title>Point Lighting</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.11.0/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
canvas {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
#uiContainer {
  top: 0;
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#ui {
  background-color: coral; 
  transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
</style>

<h3>
Drag slider to rotate
</h3>
</head>

<body>
  <p>ok</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<div id="uiContainer">
  <div id="ui">
  </div>
</div>
    

<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="3d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;

uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPosition;

uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

varying vec3 v_normal;

varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * a_position;

  // orient the normals and pass to the fragment shader
//  v_normal = mat3(u_worldInverseTranspose) * a_normal;
  v_normal = mat3(u_world) * a_normal;

  // compute the world position of the surfoace
  vec3 surfaceWorldPosition = (u_world * a_position).xyz;

  // compute the vector of the surface to the light
  // and pass it to the fragment shader
  v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPosition - surfaceWorldPosition;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="3d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// Passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
  // because v_normal is a varying it's interpolated
  // so it will not be a unit vector. Normalizing it
  // will make it a unit vector again
  vec3 normal = normalize(v_normal);

  vec3 surfaceToLightDirection = normalize(v_surfaceToLight);

  float light = dot(normal, surfaceToLightDirection);

  gl_FragColor = u_color;

  // Lets multiply just the color portion (not the alpha)
  // by the light
  gl_FragColor.rgb *= light;
}
</script>

<script>
   function RadToDegSlider(props) {
    const {min, max, value, onChange} = props;
    const [v, setV] = React.useState(radToDeg(value));
    return (
      <RangeSlider
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={v}
        onChange={(e, v) => {
          setV(v);
          onChange(degToRad(v));
        }}
      />
    );
  }

// Setup a ui.
   const domContainer = document.querySelector('#ui');

   ReactDOM.render(
    <RadToDegSlider
    value={getRotation()}
    onChange={v => {
      fRotationRadians = v;
      drawScene();
    }}
    min={-360}
    max={360} />, domContainer);  

  function getRotation() {
    return fRotationRadians;
  }

  function updateRotation(value) {
    fRotationRadians = value;
    drawScene();
  } 
</script>

<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["3d-vertex-shader", "3d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var normalLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_normal");

  // lookup uniforms
  var worldViewProjectionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_worldViewProjection");
  var worldInverseTransposeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_worldInverseTranspose");
  var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
  var lightWorldPositionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_lightWorldPosition");
  var worldLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_world");

  // Create a buffer to put positions in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Put geometry data into buffer
  setGeometry(gl);

  // Create a buffer to put normals in
  var normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = normalBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
  // Put normals data into buffer
  setNormals(gl);

  function radToDeg(r) {
    return r * 180 / Math.PI;
  }

  function degToRad(d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  var fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(50);

  var fRotationRadians = 0;

  drawScene();
  

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene() {
//    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
//    console.log(gl.canvas.width,gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Turn on culling. By default backfacing triangles
    // will be culled.
    //gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    // Enable the depth buffer
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the position attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Turn on the normal attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(normalLocation);

    // Bind the normal buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of normalBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floating point values
    var normalize = false; // normalize the data (convert from 0-255 to 0-1)
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( normalLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Compute the projection matrix
    var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    var zNear = 1;
    var zFar = 2000;
    var projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    // Compute the camera's matrix
    var camera = [100, 150, 200];
    var target = [0, 35, 0];
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(camera, target, up);

    // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
    var viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

    // Compute a view projection matrix
    var viewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);

    // Draw a F at the origin
    var worldMatrix = m4.yRotation(fRotationRadians);
//console.log('stampa');
//console.log(worldMatrix);
    // Multiply the matrices.
    var worldViewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, worldMatrix);
    var worldInverseMatrix = m4.inverse(worldMatrix);
//console.log(worldInverseMatrix);
    var worldInverseTransposeMatrix = m4.transpose(worldInverseMatrix);
//console.log(worldInverseTransposeMatrix);
    // Set the matrices
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(worldViewProjectionLocation, false, worldViewProjectionMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(worldInverseTransposeLocation, false, worldInverseTransposeMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(worldLocation, false, worldMatrix);

    // Set the color to use
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, [0.2, 1, 0.2, 1]); // green

    // set the light position
    gl.uniform3fv(lightWorldPositionLocation, [20, 30, 60]);

    // Draw the geometry.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 16 * 6;
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
  }
}

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a letter 'F'.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  var positions = new Float32Array([
          // left column front
          0,    0,  0,
          0,  150,  0,
          30,   0,  0,
          0,  150,  0,
          30, 150,  0,
          30,   0,  0,

          // top rung front
          30,   0,  0,
          30,  30,  0,
          100,  0,  0,
          30,  30,  0,
          100, 30,  0,
          100,  0,  0,

          // middle rung front
          30,  60,  0,
          30,  90,  0,
          67,  60,  0,
          30,  90,  0,
          67,  90,  0,
          67,  60,  0,

          // left column back
           0,    0,  30,
          30,    0,  30,
           0,  150,  30,
           0,  150,  30,
           30,   0,  30,
           30, 150,  30,

          // top rung back
           30,   0,  30,
          100,   0,  30,
           30,  30,  30,
           30,  30,  30,
          100,   0,  30,
          100,  30,  30,

          // middle rung back
           30,  60,  30,
           67,  60,  30,
           30,  90,  30,
           30,  90,  30,
           67,  60,  30,
           67,  90,  30,

          // top
            0,   0,   0,
          100,   0,   0,
          100,   0,  30,
            0,   0,   0,
          100,   0,  30,
            0,   0,  30,

          // top rung right
          100,   0,   0,
          100,  30,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,   0,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,   0,  30,

          // under top rung
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   30,  30,
          100,  30,  30,
          30,   30,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,  30,   0,

          // between top rung and middle
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   60,  30,
          30,   30,  30,
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   60,   0,
          30,   60,  30,

          // top of middle rung
          30,   60,   0,
          67,   60,  30,
          30,   60,  30,
          30,   60,   0,
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   60,  30,

          // right of middle rung
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   90,  30,
          67,   60,  30,
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   90,   0,
          67,   90,  30,

          // bottom of middle rung.
          30,   90,   0,
          30,   90,  30,
          67,   90,  30,
          30,   90,   0,
          67,   90,  30,
          67,   90,   0,

          // right of bottom
          30,   90,   0,
          30,  150,  30,
          30,   90,  30,
          30,   90,   0,
          30,  150,   0,
          30,  150,  30,

          // bottom
          0,   150,   0,
          0,   150,  30,
          30,  150,  30,
          0,   150,   0,
          30,  150,  30,
          30,  150,   0,

          // left side
          0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,  30,
          0, 150,  30,
          0,   0,   0,
          0, 150,  30,
          0, 150,   0]);

  // Center the F around the origin and Flip it around. We do this because
  // we're in 3D now with and +Y is up where as before when we started with 2D
  // we had +Y as down.

  // We could do by changing all the values above but I'm lazy.
  // We could also do it with a matrix at draw time but you should
  // never do stuff at draw time if you can do it at init time.
  var matrix = m4.xRotation(Math.PI);
  matrix = m4.translate(matrix, -50, -75, -15);

  for (var ii = 0; ii < positions.length; ii += 3) {
    var vector = m4.transformPoint(matrix, [positions[ii + 0], positions[ii + 1],
                 positions[ii + 2], 1]);
    positions[ii + 0] = vector[0];
    positions[ii + 1] = vector[1];
    positions[ii + 2] = vector[2];
  }

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function setNormals(gl) {
  var normals = new Float32Array([
          // left column front
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,

          // top rung front
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,

          // middle rung front
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,
          0, 0, 1,

          // left column back
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,

          // top rung back
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,

          // middle rung back
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,
          0, 0, -1,

          // top
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,

          // top rung right
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,

          // under top rung
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,

          // between top rung and middle
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,

          // top of middle rung
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 1, 0,

          // right of middle rung
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,

          // bottom of middle rung.
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,

          // right of bottom
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          1, 0, 0,

          // bottom
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,
          0, -1, 0,

          // left side
          -1, 0, 0,
          -1, 0, 0,
          -1, 0, 0,
          -1, 0, 0,
          -1, 0, 0,
          -1, 0, 0]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normals, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have all the code in this html file and I import the libraries with cdn, but I can't see the slider in the web page. I'm new to react and webgl, and don't understand where the problem is. How can I do? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code, I've created a working demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-rgb-9h18u?file=/index.html

1. You have missed babel import
2. Missing type="text/babel" on script tag
3. Slider is the correct component name

Comment: thank you so much! but if I want the slider with only one dot, shouldn't I use Continuous sliders? or Range slider?